# remove '.' of an float

Tags: javascript, floating-point

`548.705078125` output -> `548705078125`

What's the best way to do this, not using regex or `.replace('.','')`?

Comment: Any reason why not to use regular expressions or `replace`? Use the right tools for the right job!

Comment: You have excluded the best [and _only_ non-contrived[?!]] solutions from the possible answers. What a silly question!

Comment: This is actually a bad idea, period.  Remember about floating-point representation.

Comment: @vol7ron no,I need pass this number to function that acept only ints

Comment: @JackJ -___- That's easy.  `Number((548.705078125).toString().replace(".",""))`

Comment: @Jack That doesn't explain why you can't use `replace('.', '')`

Comment: @Joseph I don't want convert to string, simply it.

Comment: @JackJ Why on earth not? You can't just nix the dot in there without some kind of concatination! The float won't allow it.  Converting with Number() is not a problem and is the only solution here.

Comment: @JackJ you're asking for convoluted answers here to what should be a very simple and straightforward problem.  There are some clever solutions below, but they are just fun little problem solving exercises that should not be used in production code. As Jack said, use `Number((548.705078125).toString().replace(".",""))`. I cannot conceive of a situation where you cannot use replace, and apparently you can't explain why you can't use replace either.

Comment: Another point is why you would even want to do this... floats tend to pull random digets out of thin air. For instance `num = 50698.23434; result = num - Math.floor(num);` should result in 23434 but it doesn't.  It seems the PO would more likely need something like Math.floor(num) to stip off the decimal places... .and that's it. Otherwise the result will be arbitrary.

Comment: @JackJ You can't do that, though. These numbers are all floating point, that is, the decimals will rarely exactly equal what you see. For example, `0.1 * 0.1` returns `0.010000000000000002` (at least in Chrome). If you want to preserve significant digits you'll have to rely on either a [library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744099/javascript-bigdecimal-library) or string conversion.

Comment: @Jack, I think what people are getting at is that JavaScript wasn't built for Math.  The quickness that it executes has come at a cost.  Floating point numbers are realllly tricky, even your 32/64b processor isn't all that accurate when it comes to performing complex computations.  The defacto standard has been, if you're going to do anything Math related, you'll have to convert your number to a string, and do it the hard way.

Comment: 548.705078125 and 548705078125 are two entirely different numbers. If you have the float 548.705078125 but your function only accepts ints then 548 or 549, depending on how you want to handle rounding, would be roughly the integer equivalent of 548.705078125. Anything else is completely arbitrary, you may as well use `Math.rand`. Can you clarify your use case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look, no horrible, nasty string functions or regex!

```
function noStringsOrRegexOrDecimals(num) {
  while (num % 1 !== 0) {
    num *= 10;
  };
  return num;
}

noStringsOrRegexOrDecimals(548.705078125);
```

Yes, I'm aware that this is not a very useful function to have in your toolkit ([although it is fast](http://jsperf.com/float-point-removal-without-regex)). And that it breaks for some numbers because of how floating point math works, and that it won't work in our glorious octal future to come.

Comment: This is the only solution that doesn't use string conversion, which is what the PO wants... I have no idea why the PO doesn't want to use Number() though :\ Anyway, +1.

Comment: But it fails in many cases too EX: `noStringsOrRegexOrDecimals(548.705078121)` outputs `5487050781210001`

Comment: Math check -- Any number `mod 1` will equal zero.

Comment: @Michael In JavaScript, any _integer_ mod 1 will equal zero (ignoring any floating point representation issues), which is the point here. `alert(0.5 % 1)` returns `0.5`. Multiplying by 10 makes it 5, which "removes the decimal place" per the OP's request. It's still, of course, a bad idea to avoid using strings.

Comment: Thank you @Bryan for the gentle correction.  I've learned something new!  :-)

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
Number((548.705078125).toString().split(".").join(""))
```

Comment: Personally I prefer: `(548.705078125+'').split('.').join('')*1`

Comment: @vol7ron nice! It's a lot cleaner albiet not as readable, but very nice in any case.

Comment: Yeah, it's basically the same thing, w/o the overhead of the function calls.  If I had to solve this in production, I think the `.split().join()` would be my route as well

Comment: Opinion:  Using strings to manipulate numbers, especially given the IEEE spec for javascript numbers, is just wasteful cycles.

Comment: @MichaelHays Couldn't.Agree.More.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not using replace() or regex(), then what about split()?

```
var str = '548.705078125';
str = str.split(".");
str = str[0]+str[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

Those are weird restrictions. At the end of this `c === 548705078125`:

```
var f = 548.705078125;
var c = Math.floor(f);
f = f.toString();
for(var i = 1; (c = Math.floor(c/10)) > 0; i++);
c = parseInt(f.substring(0, i)+f.substring(i+1));
```

Comment: Woot! It's a micro-optimization haha :P (At least in chrome): http://jsperf.com/weird-not-decimal

Comment: Paul, I like your first answer the best.

Comment: @vol7ron I liked it to, but the multiplying by 10 gave weird results because of using floating point arithmetic while multiplying. If I changed the 5 at the end to a 1, the output was: `5487050781210001`

Answer (score 2):

I can't believe nobody has suggested the obvious jQuery way to do this, so that you don't need JavaScript string *or* maths functions:

```
function removeDot(num) {
  var result = $.ajax({
                       url: "removeDot.php",
                       type: "POST",
                       data: {"num" : num},
                       dataType: "text",
                       async:false
                     }).responseText;
  return Number(result);
}

console.log(removeDot(548.705078125)); // output -> 548705078125
```

I leave the implementation of "removeDot.php" as an exercise for the reader...

Answer (score 2):

You need the number to be an int... so you can pass it to a function as an int.... are you sure you don't need the following instead?

```
var num = 2395847.3428345;
Math.floor(num); // result is 2395847
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it into a String and loop over all chrs in it and look for chr == "."

Never heard of a case where you shouldnt use regexp or replace though..

Answer (score 1):

```
var n = 548.705078125.toString();
var i = n.substr(0, n.indexOf('.')) + n.substr(n.indexOf('.')+1);
alert(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

No regular expressions!

```
var num = 548.705078125;

function remove_decimal(num)
{
    var numStr = "" + num;
    var decimalIndex = numStr.indexOf('.');
    return num * Math.pow(10, (numStr.length - (decimalIndex + 1)));
}

remove_decimal(num) -> 548705078125
```

Comment: As Paul pointed out, use `548.705078121` and you'll see a math problem in the lurks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your number is already a float (for calling into a function that requires integers, I assume), you can use this:

```
floor(1e9 * x);  // where x is 548.705078125 in your case
```

`floor` will spare you any strange precision issues from your processor.